# Creating a powershell script to convert and excel worksheet to pdf

Tags: excel, powershell, pdf

I have done some searching and have gotten close but, still don't have a completely working script. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and what I need to change or add for this to work correctly.
Here is the code:

```
$path = "D:\Geoff's Files"

$dir = "D:\Geoff's Files\*.xls

$xlFixedFormat = Microsft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType" -as [type]

$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1

$latest.name

$ExcelFile = "$latest"

$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$excel.visible = $true

$Workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($ExcelFile,2,$True)

$Worksheets = $Workbook.worksheets

$Worksheet = $Workbook.worksheets.Item(1)

$Worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat($xlFixedFormat::XlTypePDF, $path)

$workbook.Close()

$excel.Quit()
```

it runs but, throws an error in Excel that says: "Document not saved. The document may be open, or an error may have been encountered when saving."

Answer (score 0):

`$path` only points to a directory - this needs to be a full save path (including file name and extension) if you're going to pass it as an argument ([see MSDN article on this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840291.aspx))

You can try and amend the existing filename and use that:

```
$saveFileName = $ExcelFile.Substring(0, $ExcelFile.LastIndexOf('.')) + .pdf"
```

Comment: I would like to have the pdf file save as the same name as the excel file. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

Tried putting in the suggestion but, still says document not saved. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
$path = "D:\Geoff's Files"

$dir = "D:\Geoff's Files\*.xls

$xlFixedFormat = Microsft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType" -as [type]

$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1

$latest.name

$ExcelFile = "$latest"

$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$excel.visible = $true

$Workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($ExcelFile,2,$True)

$Worksheets = $Workbook.worksheets

$Worksheet = $Workbook.worksheets.Item(1)

$saveFileName = "ExcelFile.Substring(0, $ExcelFile.LastIndexOf('.')) + .pdf"

$Worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat($xlFixedFormat::XlTypePDF, $saveFileName)

$workbook.Close()

$excel.Quit()
```

Comment: Please edit your original question to add further details. This is not a forum but a Q&A website.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use full path when referencing file and the use of double quotes in the `saveFileName` needs correcting. See the working code below:

---

```
$path = "D:\Geoff's Files"

$dir = "D:\Geoff's Files\*.xls

$xlFixedFormat = Microsft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType" -as [type]

$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1

$latest.name

$ExcelFile = "$latest"

$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$excel.visible = $true

### needed to add path ### $Workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($ExcelFile,2,$True)
$Workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($path + "\" + $ExcelFile,2,$True)

$Worksheets = $Workbook.worksheets

$Worksheet = $Workbook.worksheets.Item(1)

### wrong use of quotes & needed to add path ### $saveFileName = "ExcelFile.Substring(0, $ExcelFile.LastIndexOf('.')) + .pdf"
$saveFileName = $ExcelFile.Substring(0, $ExcelFile.LastIndexOf('.')) + ".pdf"
$Worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat($xlFixedFormat::XlTypePDF, $path + "\" + $saveFileName)

$workbook.Close()

$excel.Quit()
```

---